# Returning empty string from Web Service

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, web-services, wcf

I have an issue with a web service that I created: My Web service is returning Stream
(I don't want that the function return me string..just stream!) the thing is if the stream is empty it begin to download a file that is empty.
how can I enforce the the code to return me a pure empty JSON string instead of empty file.
(if lets say I'm not passing one param to its begin to download a file that is empty)

if the stream is empty I want to return empty string like that:
{"results" : [],"status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"} to the function!

Here is my Web Service:

```
Public Class Service1
    Dim m_SelPerson As String = String.Empty
    <OperationContract()>
    <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/getPersonInfo/?personID={personID}&companyCode={companyCode}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
    Public Function getPersonInfo(ByVal personID As String, ByVal companyCode As String) As Stream
        Try
            Dim dba As New DBAccess
            Dim person As New PersonInfo
            Dim ds As DataSet = dba.GetPersonInfo(personID, companyCode)
            If Not ds Is Nothing Then
                Dim dr As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)
                person = New PersonInfo
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr("UserID")) Then
                    person.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dr("UserID"))
                End If
                person.PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(dr("PersonID"))
                person.Company = dr("Company")
                person.Title = dr("Title")
                person.CellNum = dr("CellNum")
                person.EmergencyPhone = dr("EmergencyPhone")
                person.Email = dr("Email")
                person.PersonImageName = dr("PersonImageName")
                Dim oSerilzer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
                m_SelPerson = oSerilzer.Serialize(person)
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                Return New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_SelPerson))
                'Return m_SelPerson
            Else
                Return New MemoryStream(m_SelPerson)
            End If
            'Return New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_SelPerson))
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return New MemoryStream(m_SelPerson)
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You have this flagged as c# but this seems to be VB.NET, why the c# flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*beyond just setting* m_SelPerson="{""results"" : [],""status"" : ""ZERO_RESULTS""}"

Why not make it a nice xml string...

Grab the dataset, no need to parse anything out...
Use XML to make an XMDocument out of the table data, complete with columns and values. Where DS is your dataset..

```
 Dim XMLDOX As New System.Xml.XmlDocument

 Try
     XMLDOX.LoadXml(DS.GetXml)
 Catch
     ' deal with it.
 End try

  Dim ms As Io.MemoryStream
  ms = New MemoryStream(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(XMLDOX.InnerXml.ToString))
```

Then your memory stream is a nice XML table with Columns and values, as defined by the dataset table it was made from, and is real easy to use.

```
 <table1><row><UserID>something</userid><PersonID>123</PersonID></Company>... and so on...  </row></table>
```

You can test the dataset for rows first and encode a response that your app can use when its empty..

```
  if ds.tables(0).rows.count=0 then 
       ms = New MemoryStream(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("</noresults>"))
   end if
```

Comment: OP is returning JSON, not XML.  **`<WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,`**